# Do common JARs have to be repeated across WARs in an EAR?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, enterprise-library

I have a JAR file for authorization.  I need it for each of my WAR files.  All the WAR files are packaged in an EAR file.  Do I have to repeat this common JAR in every WAR, or is there a structure for common libraries?

So my example looks something like this...

```
big.ear
  - META-INF
    - MANIFEST.MF
    - application.xml
  - appl1.war
    - META-INF
      - MANIFEST.MF
    - WEB-INF
      - web.xml
      - lib
        - unique1.jar
        - unique2.jar
        - unique3.jar
        - common1.jar
    - jsps/html/etc
  - appl2.war
    - META-INF
      - MANIFEST.MF
    - WEB-INF
      - web.xml
      - lib
        - unique3.jar
        - unique4.jar
        - common1.jar
    - jsps/html/etc
  - appl3.war
    - META-INF
      - MANIFEST.MF
    - WEB-INF
      - web.xml
      - lib
        - unique5.jar
        - common1.jar
    - jsps/html/etc
```

Each of my WAR applications can see common1.jar, but it is in the EAR three times.

Where in the EAR structure could I put common1.jar so that appl1, appl2, and appl3 could see it without repeating it three times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way is to put the JARs at the root of your EAR and reference them in the `Class-Path` attribute of the WARs' `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. See [this article](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/verified/packaging.html).

Check your container's documentation to make sure it is supported.

Answer (score 1):

It’s in the JEE5 spec, chapter EE 8.2.1:

> A .ear file may contain a directory that contains libraries packaged
>   in JAR files. The library-directory element of the .ear file’s
>   deployment descriptor contains the name of this directory. If a
>   library-directory element isn’t specified, or if the .ear file does
>   not contain a deployment descriptor, the directory named **lib** is
>   used.

Answer (score -4):

Your app server should have a folder like shared/lib where you can put jar files that can be shared by multiple webapps in the same instance.

Comment: This will probably work, but I consider it bad practice.   The EAR should be self contained.

Comment: Definitely a bad practice.  What if you want to upgrade this jar?  You should be able to do that with a deployment, you shouldn't have to alter the server setup.